# Objects and instance variables in loops

Tags: design-patterns, vb.net

Is there anything wrong with doing this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        For value As Integer = 0 To 1000000
            Dim p As New Person
            p.ID = value
            p.DoSomething()
            p = Nothing
        Next
    End Sub
    Public Class Person
        Dim _ID As Integer
        Public WriteOnly Property ID() As Integer
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _ID = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Sub DoSomething()
            _ID = _ID + 1
            'Do more with ID
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

As appose to this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        For value As Integer = 0 To 1000000
            Person.DoSomething(value)
        Next
    End Sub
    Public Class Person
        Public Shared Sub DoSomething(ByVal id As Integer)
            id = id + 1
            'Do more with ID
        End Sub
    End Class

End Class
```

I have written some code similar to that in sample 1. I have read online that code 1 can cause problems when threading is involved, but I do not understand why? Are there any other problems with sample 1? Sample 1 meets my requirements better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sample1, as you call it, you have an instance field which you change. Therefore, the `Person` class you are using is **mutable**. Mutable classes are prominent to concurrency issues if a single instance is manipulated by multiple threads, **unless explicit synchronization** mechanism is *properly* involved.

In sample2, if you pass the value in the method, and you are not modifying the state of the `Person` class as you do your business logic, then the code is thread safe. No other thread can access the local variable `id` and modify it concurrently, since it is visible to the current thread only. So there is no need to apply a synchronization mechanism.

However, sample2 may not be appropriate enough for your concrete requirements. If you give more code clues on what happens in the method in question, then a more-accurate advice can be given.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the first example would be considered problematic when multiple threads are involved, is because in that example, a `Person` object maintains state (i.e. data) and it has methods that act upon that state.  There's nothing wrong with designing classes that way, per se, and it doesn't mean that the class cannot be used by multi-threaded applications safely--it just makes multi-threading more difficult.

For instance, consider this example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim _p As New Person

    Private Sub DoWork(value As Integer)
        _p.Id = value
        _p.DoSomething()
    End Sub

    ' ... Code that calls DoWork on multiple threads ...

    Public Class Person
        Dim _id As Integer
        Public WriteOnly Property Id() As Integer
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _id = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Sub DoSomething()
            _id = _id + 1
            'Do more with Id
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Let's say that in the above example, the `DoWork` method is called from two different threads simultaneously, and the order that the lines are processed is like this:

1. Thread A sets `_p.Id = 1`
2. Thread B sets `_p.Id = 10`
3. Thread A calls `_p.DoSomething` which increments `_p.Id` to `11`
4. Thread B calls `_p.DoSomething` which increments `_p.Id` to `12`

As you can see, that would certainly be undesired behavior.  There are three ways to fix this problem.  The first way is to use one of the available synchronization techniques to make sure that only one thread uses the object at a time, for instance:

```
Private Sub DoWork(value As Integer)
    SyncLock _p
        _p.Id = value
        _p.DoSomething()
    End SyncLock
End Sub
```

By synchronously locking on the object, if a second thread tries to call `DoWork` at the same time, the second thread's execution will be blocked (i.e. hung) until the first thread's call to `DoWork` is complete.  The problem with this approach is that, at least to some extent, it defeats the purpose of multi-threading because only one thread can do that part of the work at a time.

The second way to fix this would be to have each thread create a new `Person` object so that they don't interfere with each other.  For instance, instead of having the `_p` object declared as a class-level field, you could just create a new `Person` object inside the `DoWork` method, like this:

```
Private Sub DoWork(value As Integer)
    Dim p As New Person()
    p.Id = value
    p.DoSomething()
End Sub
```

The third way to fix this would be to use your second example.  By fixing the `Person` class so that it is a stateless class, multiple threads can call the same object as often at the same time as necessary because the data is stored outside of the `Person` class.  So, as long as each thread is instantiating a separate object to store the data before passing it into the `Person` object, all the threads can share the same `Person` object without needing to worry about collisions.

Comment: Thanks.  +1.  I assume that if I do not create any Threads myself i.e. using the Thread class, then there is no issues?

Comment: It's not a matter of how you create your threads--it's a matter, rather, of how the threads use your `Person` class.  If multiple threads share the same `Person` object, then you should have some concerns.  If they each use their own independent `Person` object, then it's not a concern (unless the `Person` class contains shared members or shares dependencies between instances).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment.  I assume that if I do not explicitly create any Threads then there is no issue to even think about? The reason I ask is because I know that ASP.NET uses MTA's (multi threaded apartments).

Comment: Correct.  If you are not explicitly making your code multi-threaded, none of it is an immediate concern.

Comment: Thanks I assume that the fact that ASP.NET uses MTA is insignificant.  I know what MTA's are in theory but I do not understand the relationship between MTAs and threads (System.Thread).  Thanks again.

Comment: Can you confirm that MTA's are insignificant if Threads (system.thread) are not used?

Comment: I can't speak absolutely authoritatively on that, but from what I do know, I would say that you don't have to worry about it.  It's not an issue of whether or not the threads are MTA, it's just a matter of whether or not the threads are sharing objects.  In a typical ASP.NET situation, it seems highly-unlikely that your threads are going to be sharing objects with each other without you doing so quite on purpose.

Comment: Thanks.  Finally, is sample 1 Person an example of a service class as it is providing a service to the form?

Comment: I can't answer that.  Sounds like a great new question to ask :)